# "[Vega Err] [object XMLHttpRequest]" error when trying to plot a vincent chart in folium based maps in python

Tags: python, json, vega, folium, vincent

I'm experimenting with the folium library to plot charts in markers within maps. Doing this using the folium library in python.

The code is pretty simple. As follows,

```
import folium
import vincent

bar = vincent.Bar([1,2,3,4])
popup1 = folium.Popup(max_width=1200,).add_child(folium.Vega(bar,width=500,height=500))
m = folium.Map([47.3489, -124.708], zoom_start=5)
folium.RegularPolygonMarker([47.3489, -124.708], popup=popup1).add_to(m)
m.save("/home/map.html")
```

The code runs and creates the the html map. When I click on the marker, the block to render the chart comes up, but within it I see no chart. Also, before showing the chart, the browse throws an error saying 
[Vega Err] [object XMLHttpRequest]

Comment: Have you opened a local web server ?